# Remove items from vuex store

Tags: cookies, vue.js, vuex

I have use vuex with vuex-persistedstate (Cookie) to store user information while the user is logged in. 
Now I need to remove the cookie, or parts of it when the user loggs out.

The plugin has the "removeItem" property but how can I access this function or more general, how can I remove something from the store.

My code:

```
import {Store} from 'vuex'
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'
import * as Cookies from 'js-cookie'
    //...
const store = new Store({
            state: {
                user: {},
                apitoken: {},
              ...
            },
            plugins: [
                createPersistedState({
                    storage: {
                        getItem: key => Cookies.get(key),
                        // Please see https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie#json, on how to handle JSON.
                        setItem: (key, value) =>
                            Cookies.set(key, value, { expires: 3, secure: true }),
                        removeItem: key => Cookies.remove(key)
                    }
                })
            ],
            mutations: {
                SET_USER(state, user) {
                    state.user = user;
                },
                SET_APITOKEN(state, apitoken) {
                    state.apitoken = apitoken;
                },
                LOGOUT(state, key) {
        //HERE I NEED SOME THING LIKE "removeItem(key)"
                    state.clean();
                },
            },
            actions: {
                logout(context){
                    context.commit('LOGOUT', 'apitoken');
                }
        });
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `state[key] = null`?

Comment: @EmileBergeron this works fine to null one item. But how to remove the Cookie?

Comment: Your question is unclear.